# Example of Single-Page Application (SPA) using Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, single-page-application, polymer-1.0

Can someone supply examples of Single-Page Applications (SPA) using Polymer 1.0?

Answer (score 9):

The [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/) uses a Single Page App structure.  Their Github page is [here](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Made with Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/spa.html) and [Built with Polymer](http://builtwithpolymer.org).

Both of these are curated sites showcasing SPAs using Polymer 1.0.

And [here is an article](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/spa.html).

Comment: OP is asking about examples for Polymer 1.0. The first link you provided is directly linking to version 0.5. And I'm surprised if even one of the projects in the second link is made with Polymer 1.0. And the third link is also directly linking to version 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

One page scroller app example with polymer + iscroll.

https://github.com/sgoran/polymer-spa

Comment: A single index.html of 25k(!) lines I would not recommend to anyone …

Comment: That's the whole framework with all imports included with vulcanize.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Polymer session on Google IO 2015. The video https://youtu.be/fD2As5RmM8Q?t=25m52s explains how it is done Polymer way.

The code is available at https://github.com/googlechrome/ioweb2015

The Santa tracker available at https://github.com/google/santa-tracker-web is also a single page app. However the presenter does not get into details on that.